# Is it possible to make a webdav client in React Native without the need of native code?

Tags: react-native, webdav

Basically the title says everything.
I want to create a basic WebDav Client to create, download and delete files from the webdav Server.
But I was unable to find a library which is able to achieve this in React Native.
Any suggestions?
I really don't want to write native code for it...

Another thing is that basic authentication has to be possible.

Thanks,
TK

Comment: Have you looked if you could use something for existant JS libraries? https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=webdav&type=Repositories

Comment: Yes I have... but they rely as far as I can tell on node JS base packages wich are not compatible with React Native

Comment: Few of them on the first page, yes but not all of them . A lot are unmaintained but in my knowledge WebDav did not really change since a couple of year so the libraries did not necessarly had to change too.

Comment: I haven't found any that is capable of doing what I need, Do you know any?

Comment: What about this one? https://github.com/OpenMarshal/npm-WebDAV-Client

Comment: Same issue... one of the first I tried acutally

Answer (score 0):

[webdav-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdav-fs) works on React Native after installing [react-native-crypto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-crypto), [stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream) and shimming Node.js core modules (as described here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-crypto).

Another step I had to take is to uncomment `require("crypto");` in the file `shim.js` created by `rn-nodeify`.

Answer (score 0):

[webdav](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdav) seems to work.

But in order to compile, I had to install a few standard node modules that are not in react native : stream-browserify (to replace stream), events, buffer, + I replaced crypto by md5.

not sure, but typescript support for the project may be necessary, too.